# Save time running code with large datasets?

Tags: sas, frequency, proc, large-data

I need to find the frequency of each SA1 group in the following:

```
data have
input SA1;
datalines;
AA1
AA1 
AA1
AA2
AA2
AB1
 .
 .
 ;
run;
```

I have over **1,000,000 rows** of SA1 observations. Is there an efficient way to find the frequency for each SA1 group?

Comment: Proc freq is one way. 1 million rows is trivial to SAS.

Comment: well, it depends. if strings are composed by 3 chars, on my standard pc it took 0.54 seconds with proc freq of 1.000.000 observations. 100 chars were 3.87 seconds.